# Porque mi tabla esta recibiendo el tipoCuenta_id como null?

Tags: html, laravel-7

Buenas estoy tratando de pasarle el tipoCuenta_id a mi tabla customers mediante un foreach que itera un dropdown en la vista con un formulario.

La vista es la siguiente:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="tipoCuenta">Tipo de cuenta</label>
                            <select name="tipoCuenta" id="" class="form-control">
                                <option value="">Seleccione el tipo de cuenta</option>
                                @foreach ($tipoCuentas as $key => $tipoCuenta)
                                <option value="{{$tipoCuenta->id}}">{{$tipoCuenta->tipoCuenta}}</option>
                                
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
```

Hasta este punto todo anda perfecto, en el dropdown me aparecen todos los tipos de cuenta de mi base de datos, pero luego cuando paso los valores en la vista para mostrar todos los registros me devuelve el siguiente error.

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'tipoCuenta_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `customers` (`holding`, `company`, `legal_entity`, `tipoCuenta_id`, `mobile_no`, `email`, `country`, `state`, `city`, `address`, `postal`, `cuit`, `website`, `id_parentCompany`, `created_by`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (GTT, Global Tec Trade, Global Tec Trade Srl, ?, 12345678, gtt@gmail.com, Argentina, Buenos Aires, Saveedra, Superi 4430, 1670, 1312321, gtt.com.ar, ?, 1, 2021-08-10 16:26:36, 2021-08-10 16:26:36))
```

Donde claramente dice el error que el campo tipoCuenta_id recibe null.

Para mostrar la informacion utilizo la siguiente tabla en mi vista:

```
<td style="display: none;">{{$key+1}}</td>
                            <td>{{$customer->holding }}</td>
                            <td>{{$customer->company }}</td>
                            <td>{{$customer->legal_entity }}</td>
                            <td>{{$customer['tipoCuenta']['tipoCuenta']}}</td>
                            <td>{{$customer->mobile_no }}</td>                         
                            <td>{{$customer->email}}</td>                            
                            <td>{{$customer->country}}</td>
                            <td>{{$customer->state}}</td>
                            <td>{{$customer->city}}</td>
                            <td>{{$customer->address}}</td>
                            <td>{{$customer->postal }}</td>
                            <td>{{$customer->cuit}}</td>
                            <td>{{$customer->website}}</td>
```

La relacion entre customer y tipoCuenta esta formada de la siguiente manera:

tipoCuenta.php:

```
class tipoCuenta extends Model
{
    public function customer(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class, 'customer_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Customer.php:

```
public function tipoCuenta(){
        return $this->hasOne(tipoCuenta::class);
    }
```

Y esta es mi migracion de la tabla tipoCuentas:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tipo_cuentas', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('tipoCuenta')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Migracion de customers:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('holding')->nullable();
            $table->string('company')->nullable();
            $table->string('legal_entity')->nullable();
            $table->string('mobile_no')->nullable();
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('country')->nullable();
            $table->string('state')->nullable();
            $table->string('city')->nullable();
            $table->string('address')->nullable();
            $table->string('postal')->nullable();
            $table->string('cuit');
            $table->string('website')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('tipoCuenta_id');
            $table->foreign('tipoCuenta_id')->references('id')->on('tipo_cuentas');
            $table->tinyInteger('status')->default('1');
            $table->integer('id_parentCompany')->nullable();
            $table->integer('created_by')->nullable();
            $table->integer('updated_by')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Por ultimo en mi customers controller en el metodo store le estoy pasando el id de tipoCuentas de la siguiente manera:

```
 public function store(Request $request){
        $customer = new Customer();
        $customer->holding = $request->holding;        
        $customer->company = $request->company;
        $customer->legal_entity = $request->legal_entity;
        $customer->tipoCuenta_id = $request->tipoCuenta_id;        
        $customer->mobile_no = $request->mobile_no;        
        $customer->email = $request->email;       
        $customer->country = $request->country;
        $customer->state = $request->state;
        $customer->city = $request->city;
        $customer->address = $request->address;
        $customer->postal = $request->postal;
        $customer->cuit = $request->cuit;
        $customer->website = $request->website;
        $customer->id_parentCompany = $request->id_parentCompany;
        $customer->created_by = Auth::user()->id;
        $customer->save();
        Session::flash('success');
        return redirect()->route('customers.view');
    }
```

Si alguien sabe como solucionar este error se los agradecería mucho.